# Thread won't wake up

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I'm trying to simulate a simple thermostat, using multi-threading. I have a desired temperature value saved on lblDesiredTemp and another label to display current temperature lblCurrentTemp. The problem occur when while there's more than two active thread in system. the threads which are waiting won't wake up!

this is my method:

```
'private synchronized void ApplySetting()
    {
        Thread tempetureUpdater = new Thread() 
             {
                @Override
                public synchronized void run() 
                {
                    txtLog.setText(txtLog.getText() + "\n" + this.getName());
                    try 
                    {
                        while(!isDone)
                            this.wait();
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
                    {
                        txtLog.setText(txtLog.getText() + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
                    }
```

int Max = Integer.parseInt(lblDesiredTemp.getText());
                int Current = Integer.parseInt(lblCurrentTemp.getText());

                txtLog.setText(txtLog.getText() + "\n" + Current +  " to " + Max);

                if(Current > Max)
                {
                    isDone = false;

                    for (int i = Current; i > Max; i--)
                    {
                        lblGasStatus.setText("Off");
                        try 
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                            decreaseTemeture();
                        } 
                        catch (InterruptedException ex) 
                        {
                            txtLog.setText(txtLog.getText() + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                    txtLog.setText(txtLog.getText() + "\n" + this.getName() + " done!");
                    isDone = true;
                    this.notifyAll();
                } 
                else
                {
                    isDone = false;

                    for (int i = Current; i < Max; i++)
                    {
                        lblGasStatus.setText("On");
                        try 
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                            increaseTemeture();
                        } 
                        catch (InterruptedException ex) 
                        {
                            txtLog.setText(txtLog.getText() + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                    txtLog.setText(txtLog.getText() + "\n" + this.getName() + " done!");
                    isDone = true;
                    this.notifyAll();
                }
                // Report the result using invokeLater().
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()   
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });
            }
         };
         tempetureUpdater.start();
}

What's the problem?!

Answer (score 4):

> The problem occur when while there's more than two active thread in system. the threads which are waiting won't wake up!

Well how would you expect them to? You're only ever notifying the "current" object, which is a new thread. When one thread finishes, it will call `this.notifyAll`, but that won't wake up *other* threads.

Additionally, I would *strongly* urge you to change other things about how you're writing this:

- An anonymous inner class of this size is crying out to be broken out into a proper named class
- The `ApplySetting` method name doesn't follow Java naming conventions. Ditto various of your variable names.
- It's generally a bad idea to extend `Thread` - implement `Runnable` instead, and pass the `Runnable` to the thread constructor
- You shouldn't call `wait` and `notify`/`notifyAll` on `Thread` objects, as `Thread` uses that for signalling itself
- It's generally a good idea to synchronize on private references which *no* other code is going to use for synchronization or signalling
- As noted in Marko's answer, it's almost always a bad idea to make the `run` method synchronized. Given the previous bullet point, I prefer not to make any whole *methods* synchronized, instead synchronizing on individual references within methods
- It looks like you're trying to update UI elements within a non-UI thread; I believe that will fail. (You need to use `invokeLater`)

Comment: I do plan to update UI elements. a button invoke this applySetting method. I don't want my GUI to freeze that's why I used thread class. This is my first multithread coding and at the same time my first java coding experience. i just wanted to learn the logic before making it neat.

Comment: @Elham: It's fine to use threads, but you shouldn't be accessing UI elements *directly* in that thread. It would be better to fetch all the information you need from the UI (desired and current temperature, for example) before you start, then create the thread to use those, then use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to update the UI when you need to. Alternatively, do *everything* in the UI thread, but use a timer instead of `Thread.sleep`

Comment: A good option is to use `SwingWorker` instead of raw threads. There you already have been provided with a method that runs in its own thread and another method that runs after that in the GUI thread.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:when I use SwingUtilities.invokeLater, GUI will freeze till it reaches the desired temperature. isn't there a solution which supports recursive threads?

Comment: @Elham: I wasn't suggesting using it for *everything* - just the UI access. Using a SwingTimer would probably be a better plan overall though.

Answer (score 0):

Never mark the `run` method as `synchronized`. Not only here, **ever**. Also, your `notifyAll` will attempt to wake up the very thread it runs in. This can't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `this` reference in `this.wait()` and `this.notifyAll()` so that it refers to the outer object, not the object of your anonymous `Thread` class.  This could be as simple as writing `MyClass.this.wait()` and `MyClass.this.notifyAll()`, where `MyClass` is the class in which your `applySettings` method is found.

However, I also recommend making the changes listed by Jon Skeet.

Comment: when I put my class name it invoke this exception: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Comment: OK, that happens when you call `wait`, without being in a `synchronized` block on the object that you call `wait` on.  Change the `synchronized` keyword on the `run` method to a `synchronized(MyClass.this){ ... }`.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get what you just said. you mean something like this: public synchronized(ControllerGUI.this) void run() ??

Comment: No, I mean put a synchronized block inside the method.  Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html